# How to redirect from a python script to another scripts taking user input

Tags: python-2.7

I have 2 python scripts Script1.py and Script2.py respectively. I create another script called Value.py in which I want to take a user input as either Script1 as a string which would run Script1.py or Script2 which would run Script2.py.

Please can someone help me out in making this short script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than running the scripts separately, you should encapsulate their contents into a function and either:

1. Put all three functions into one `.py` file (if they're short); or
2. `import` the two existing functions into `value.py` (if they're long).

Then `value` simply looks like:

```
from Script1 import func1 # only for option 2
from Script2 import func2 # only for option 2

def value():
    ...
    if user_input == "Script1":
        func1()
    else:
        func2()

def func1(): # only for option 1
    ...

def func2(): # only for option 1
    ...

value() # call value
```

Comment: from Script1.py import Query() is throwing a syntax error saying Invalid Syntax

Comment: Ditch the `.py` and the parentheses `()`